# Onclick function is not working on a particular span

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am having a problem that my Onclick event is not triggering on a tag. The same onclick event is working properly when binded to a image.
I am making a follow and unfollow function in php and jquery .It is not working so I decided to test a alert after clicking the follow or unfollow button . Then also it is not working .
The code is this

```
<?php
if ($my_id != $id) {
    $check_follow_not      = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM follower WHERE user_id='$my_id' AND following='$id'");
    $check_follow_not_rows = mysqli_num_rows($check_follow_not);
    
    if ($check_follow_not_rows == 0) {
        $editfollowunfollow = "<span class='btn_f_uf'><a onclick=\"don();\">Follow</a></span>";
    } else {
        $editfollowunfollow = "<span class='btn_f_uf'><a onclick=\"don();\">UnFollow</a></span>";
    }
} else {
    $editfollowunfollow = "<span class='btn_f_uf'><a>Edit Profile</a></span>";
}
echo $editfollowunfollow;
?>
```

The php code is okay, the problem is with the jquery code

The don() function is this

```
function don(){
    alert();
}
```

This function is working fine on a image in same file . But not working in the follow and unfollow button.

Thanks in advance . I appreciate all answer

**EDIT**

Css code of class btn_f_uf

```
.btn_f_uf{
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    padding:10px;
    background:#53a93f;
    border-radius:5px;
    color:white;
    float:right;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-top:25px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

The profile page whole code

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
    <title>Profcee</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/check.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        include "function/checklogin.php";
        include "config/connect.php";
        
        $my_profile_image = $_SESSION['profile_image'];
        $my_email =  $_SESSION['email'];
        $my_id = $_SESSION['id'] ;
        $my_name = ucfirst($_SESSION['name']);
        $my_background_image = $_SESSION['background_image'];
        
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $check = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
        $check_num = mysqli_num_rows($check);
        if($check_num == 0){
                header("location:home.php");
        }else{
            $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);
            $name = ucfirst($fetch['name']);
            $email = $fetch['email'];
            $profile_image = $fetch['profile'];
            $background_image = $fetch['background'];
            
            if($my_id != $id){ 
                $check_follow_not = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM follower WHERE user_id='$my_id' AND following='$id'");
                $check_follow_not_rows = mysqli_num_rows($check_follow_not);
                
                if($check_follow_not_rows == 0){ 
                    $editfollowunfollow = "<span class='btn_f_uf'><a class='btns'>Follow</a></span>";
                } else{ 
                    $editfollowunfollow = "<span class='btn_f_uf'><a class='btns'>UnFollow</a></span>";
                }
            }else{
                $editfollowunfollow = "<span class='btn_f_uf'><a>Edit Profile</a></span>";
            }
?>
<?php
include "header.php"; ?>
<div id="profile_full">
<div id="background_image">
    <img src="<?php echo $background_image;?>" width="100%" height="400px" onclick="don();">
</div>
<div id="profile_image">
    <img src="<?php echo $profile_image?>" width="250px" height="250px">
</div>
<div id="profile_header">
    <h1><?php echo $name;?></h1>
    
                    <div id="profile_follower">
                    <?php 
                        $follower = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM follower WHERE following='$id'");
                        $follower_count = mysqli_num_rows($follower);
                    ?>
                    <h2><?php echo $follower_count;?> Follower</h2> 
                    </div>
                    <div id="profile_following">
                    <?php 
                        $following = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM follower WHERE user_id='$id'");
                        $following_count = mysqli_num_rows($following);
                    ?>
                    <h2><?php echo $following_count;?> following </h2>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $editfollowunfollow;?>
            
</div>
</div>
<?php
include "footer.php";
?>
<?php 
}
}else{
    header("location:home.php");
}
?>
```

The check.js file

```
$(document).on("click",".btns", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert();      
});
```

Comment: Instead of `onclick` why don't you try bind click on span using `.on`?. Give some class to those buttons say `btns` and the `$(".btns").on("click", don)`

Comment: Then also not working @Sandeep Nayak

Answer (score 0):

Like other said, give it class name `btns` and remove`onclick` inline javascript on that anchor tag :

```
.....
if($check_follow_not_rows == 0){ 
   $editfollowunfollow = "<span class='btn_f_uf'><a class='btns'>Follow</a></span>";
} else{ 
   $editfollowunfollow = "<span class='btn_f_uf'><a class='btns'>UnFollow</a></span>";
}
....
```

And in js code :

```
$(document).on("click",".btns", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert();      
});
```

If you wanna stick with `function don()`, use this(*but must be sure to remove onclick inline javascript*) :

```
$(document).on("click",".btns", don );
```

In `don` function :

```
function don(){
  alert();
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Not working @Norlikazmey. But if I put like this  $(document).on("click",".btns", don()  );  it is triggering the function automatically

Comment: Which implementation above did you used?

Comment: Above code have two method to achive that. Which one you use?

Comment: you cant use like `$(document).on("click",".btns", don() );` since `don()` will invoke automatically like we call it rather than define it.

Comment: You have any styling attached into this `btn_f_uf` css class?

Comment: So what should I do to perform  different function on tags

Comment: Alert is an only a trial function on that a tag I will make another function that will the make my follow system working

Comment: Yes I have an styling attached to btn_f_uf

Comment: I see that, so weird. Something like a bug interfere your code, see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/dptt74cw/ looking fine. Any error you got from console anyway?

Comment: It is working fine in jsfiddle . May be other code is affecting it . If you want I can give you the whole code of the site

Comment: I share it on stackoverflow or can you give me your email address

Comment: wait I will give you the profile file code in stackoverflow only

Comment: Everything looks fine. Ever try put check.js inside footer section?

Comment: Not working . Have tried all thing then also not working

Comment: Can't help you mate, cant produce the answer seems everything looking  fine for me.

Comment: No problem . I am planning to start from beginning